# How to check the right login data in access form

Tags: vba, ms-access, authentication, uppercase, lowercase

I've created a nice login form in access. The problem is that I can login altough I use upper- or lowercase for the username or password...

How can I check the right login data which are in the table?

I use this code at the moment:

```
If Nz(DLookup("Login", "Employee", _
                  "DBPass='" & Me!DBPass & "'"), "") = "'" & Me.User & "'" Then
        MsgBox "The User doesn't exist!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Check"
        Me.User.SetFocus
                  End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you keep with the default, however, you can check case with [StrComp](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/StrComp-Function-a9a4531e-3b2a-4218-b139-f7442bc10b96)

```
 StrComp("Abc","Abc",vbBinaryCompare)
```

is equal to 0 but

```
 StrComp("Abc","ABC",vbBinaryCompare)
```

is equal to 1.